# How to Display an Array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

so I'm new to coding and I've decided to learn C# with the whole Covid-19 going on, and I've run into a small problem if anybody can assist me.

I'm just writing a basic C# program to allow the user to input 5 numbers into an array and then display the array, but for some reason, I only display the number 5, not the whole array.

Please find my code:  ( if anyone can make it easier for me please help me lol (: )

```
  int[] numbers = new int[5];
  int num = 0;
  int i = 0;

  Console.WriteLine("This porgram allows the user to input 5 numbers into an array");
  Console.Write("--------------------------------------------------------------");
  Console.WriteLine("\n");

  for ( i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i ++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Please input number");
    num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  }

  for (i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
  {
     Console.ReadLine(); 
     Console.WriteLine("Your array is: " , numbers );
  }

  Console.WriteLine();
```

// any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Start learning about the indexes as well `Console.WriteLine("Your array is: " , numbers[i] );`

Comment: inside loop, use ``numbers[i]``, outside loop, use ``Console.WriteLine("Your array is: " , string.join(",", numbers) );``

Comment: thank you, Salah and Sajid, greatly appreciated! (:

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1) You haven't put the number coming in. After

```
num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

put

```
 numbers[i] = num;
```

Though in fact `num` is superfluous, so you could just have

```
 numbers[i]= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

2) In the second loop you need to display the specific array element:

```
   Console.WriteLine("Your array item is: " , numbers[i] );
```

Also, not sure what the `ReadLine()` in the second loop is for - just means the users has to hit return to see each number.

It's worth mentioning a few other issues in the code:

1. Variables should be declared as close as possible to where they are used. this `i` should be declared separately for each for loop - `for(int i = 0; ...` and `num` should be declared inside the loop (though as mentioned, it's redundant).
2. Be clear on the difference between `Console.Write()` and `Console.WriteLine()`. `WriteLine()` simply adds a `\n` to whatever is displayed. Thus it would be clearer (for the same output to have:

   `Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------");`
   `Console.WriteLine();`

Answer (score -1):

here is code:
it is the basic syntax of displaying an array.

```
  public class Work  
  {  
   public static void Main()  
     {  
       int[] arr = new int[5]; 
       int i;  
       Console.Write("\nRead & Print elements of an array:\n");
       Console.Write("-----------------------------------------\n");    

       Console.Write("Input 5 elements in the array :\n");  
       for(i=0; i<5; i++)  
        {  
          Console.Write("element - {0} : ",i);
          arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());         
        }  

         Console.Write("\nElements in array are: ");  
         for(i=0; i<5; i++)  
         {  
           Console.Write("{0}  ", arr[i]);  
         } 
           Console.Write("\n"); 
      }
   }
```